# Hovermode: 'x unified' not working with Dash

Tags: plotly-dash

I'm trying to use the 'x unified' hovermode in my plot

Here's the (relevant) code:

```
fig.update_traces(
    mode="markers+lines",)
fig.update_layout(
    hovermode='x unified')
```

In my localhost, I see: [image: localhost image]
But in my server (deployed on AWS), I see: [image: server image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked that you are running the same versions of Dash/Plotly in both environments?

Comment: @emher ah, thank you so much. I was running two different versions, fixed it and it's working perfectly!